# Syntactic error during the print of a class properties

Tags: python, class

It has been created a class which describes a person (name, address etc.). .It must be printing all the properties whichThe code it is in the follow lines

```
class Person:
    personNo=0
    def _init_(unit,first_name,last_name,age,address):
            unit.personsfirstname=first_name
            unit.lastname=last_name
            unit.personsage=age
            unit.address=address
            unit.personNo+=1
    def ShowInfo(unit):
            print("Ονομα: "+unit.personsfirstname+ "Επιθετο: "+unit.lastname+ "Ηλικια: "+unit.personsage+ "Οδος: "+unit.address=address)#The problem is here
            


person1=Person("George","Stefanopoulos","55","Alpha street 33")
person2=Person("Μαρια","Πενταγιωτισα","25","Παπαλαμπρενας 28")
```

So, when the code is executed it is appeared error: expression can not contain assignment perhaps you meant "=="? .The problem it is appeared where is located the note. It must be noted that this code is based another example code which works perfectly

Comment: what are you trying to do with `+unit.address=address)`? Did you mean `+` not `=`? And it is `__init__` not `_init_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the constructor should be `__init__` and not `_init_` 
Second, you have an `=` inside the `print` function where you try to create the output string. 
I suggest to use `__str__` method:

```py
class Person:
    personNo=0
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,age,address):
            self.personsfirstname=first_name
            self.lastname=last_name
            self.personsage=age
            self.address=address
            self.personNo+=1

    def __str__(self):
            s = "Ονομα: "+self.personsfirstname+ " Επιθετο: "+self.lastname+ " Ηλικια: "+self.personsage+ " Οδος: "+self.address
            return s
            


person1=Person("George","Stefanopoulos","55","Alpha street 33")
person2=Person("Μαρια","Πενταγιωτισα","25","Παπαλαμπρενας 28")

# thanks to __str__ method, you can do:
print(person1)
Ονομα: George Επιθετο: Stefanopoulos Ηλικια: 55Ο δος: Alpha street 33
print(person2)
Ονομα: Μαρια Επιθετο: Πενταγιωτισα Ηλικια: 25Οδος: Παπαλαμπρενας 28
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used to assign value. 
Supposing you want to display the address as you did for the name, try like this:

```
class Person:
    personNo=0
    def __init__(unit,first_name,last_name,age,address):
            unit.personsfirstname=first_name
            unit.lastname=last_name
            unit.personsage=age
            unit.address=address
            unit.personNo+=1
    def ShowInfo(unit):
            print("Ονομα: "+unit.personsfirstname+ "Επιθετο: "+unit.lastname+ "Ηλικια: "+unit.personsage+ "Οδος: "+ unit.address)
            


person1=Person("George","Stefanopoulos","55","Alpha street 33")
person2=Person("Μαρια","Πενταγιωτισα","25","Παπαλαμπρενας 28")
```

If you want to simply return `True` or `False` for address, but not sure why would you do that, do this:

```
class Person:
    personNo=0
    def __init__(unit,first_name,last_name,age,address):
            unit.personsfirstname=first_name
            unit.lastname=last_name
            unit.personsage=age
            unit.address=address
            unit.personNo+=1
    def ShowInfo(unit):
            print("Ονομα: "+unit.personsfirstname+ "Επιθετο: "+unit.lastname+ "Ηλικια: "+unit.personsage+ "Οδος: "+str(unit.address==address))
            


person1=Person("George","Stefanopoulos","55","Alpha street 33")
person2=Person("Μαρια","Πενταγιωτισα","25","Παπαλαμπρενας 28")
```

Also, you used `_init_` and the constructor can be defined using `__init__`.

Not having the right way declared constructor, you're getting an error for trying to create a new instance of class `Person` with some arguments. Your function `_init_` is a normal `method` of the class.

Comment: It is executed this code and appeared the error:    person1=Person("George","Stefanopoulos","55","Alpha street 33")
TypeError: Person() takes no arguments

Comment: I didn't see that you use `_init_` instead of `__init__`. I've updated the code. Not having the right `__init__` function you will not have a constructor for the function.